# What ressources are necessary for compiling bootstrap.css from bootstrap.less?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

For a project i'm working on i wanted to use a customized version of Bootstrap. After playing around with it it seemed quite clear to me, how Bootstrap works. There is a central .less file, bootstrap.less, which bundles in all the other .less files fullfilling certain tasks. My plan was to adapt bootstrap.less and variables.less, which would have been sufficient fo my purpose.

So i did download the complete less folder of the twitter bootstrap git repository at  https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/master/less

and i installed less.app for Mac OS X, set all Bootstrap files to be watched and only bootstrap.css to be recompiled each time i changed any .less file. Up to this point i did not change any of the files, but did recompile bootstrap.less, which gave me a new bootstrap.css

Now my problem is, that the newly compiled bootstrap.css (compiled from the unchanged files downloaded from the bootstrap git repository) looks completely different from the bootstrap.css that comes with the bootstrap download, and it behaves different as well.

bootstrap.css directly downloaded starts like this:

```
/*!
 * Bootstrap v2.3.1
 *
 * Copyright 2012 Twitter, Inc
 * Licensed under the Apache License v2.0
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Designed and built with all the love in the world @twitter by @mdo and @fat.
 */

.clearfix {
  *zoom: 1;
}

.clearfix:before,
```

and the same 15 lines in bootstrap.css compiled from the unchanged bootstrap.less looks like this:

```
/*! normalize.css v2.1.3 | MIT License | git.io/normalize */
article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
main,
nav,
section,
summary {
  display: block;
}
```

bootstrap.less looks like this (first 15 lines only):

```
// Core variables and mixins
@import "variables.less";
@import "mixins.less";

// Reset
@import "normalize.less";
@import "print.less";

// Core CSS
@import "scaffolding.less";

@import "type.less";
@import "code.less";
@import "grid.less";
@import "tables.less";
```

And there is a lot more differences, completely different behaviour and no idea why this is happening. So heres my questions:

- Should compiling like i describe work?
- Are there some important ressources i did miss?

I'd be glad for every little tip helping to find a solution to this...

Comment: You just compare different bootstrap versions. Your bootstrap.css is v 2.3.1 and https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/master/less is v3.0.x .

Comment: As for that "big comment header": it is not included in any less files but added by those build scripts they use ([recess](https://github.com/twitter/recess) etc...)

Comment: And one more problem - it seems that less.app is shipped with VERY old  less version so it may eventually fail to properly compile recent bootstrap files (as they do use a few modern less features here and there). Unless less.app has some sort of auto-update functionality that can download and install up-to-date less.js version it is built upon.

Comment: Use the less files of 2.3.1 now, theses work well with less.app. The less compiler of less.app uses less 1.3, which is not compatible with the newest bootstrap version.

Comment: @seven-phases-max: post this as an answer and i'll accept it.

Comment: Ah, I'm fine with this right here. I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score -2):

You simply need a compiler that will read the .less code you have and convert it into .css. I would personally recommend [SimpLESS](http://wearekiss.com/simpless). They offer a compiler that can do exactly what you are looking for, including a drag and drop project folder option.

**Update:**

They offer css-minification, on-the-fly compilation, backwards @import parsing, displaying of syntax errors, cross-browser css-prefix, automatic less-updater, out of the box notifications, and it works with Twitter Bootstrap.

Comment: Less.app is a compiler. What i'm looking for is the reason why it does not create the same bootstrap.css as provided by Twitter.